# Yii 1.1 - Dropdown with extended textfield option

Tags: yii

I am having problems with the code below. While I can save the value of 'Car', I am unable to save value for 'Others'. 'Others' value is set as textfield while 'Car' has been predefined.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'transport_allowance'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'transport_allowance',array('Car'=>'Car','Others'=>'Others'),array('onchange'=>'return muFun(this.value)')); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'transport_allowance'); ?>
</div>


<div id="others" style="display:none">
            <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'transport_allowance'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'transport_allowance'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'transport_allowance'); ?>
            </div>    
</div>

<div id="car" style="display:none">
            <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->hiddenField($model,'transport_allowance',array('value'=>'450')); ?>
            </div>    
</div>

<script>
function muFun(obj){
            if(obj=="Car"){
            document.getElementById('car').style.display="block"; 
            document.getElementById('others').style.display="none"; 
            }else if(obj=="Others"){
            document.getElementById('others').style.display="block";
            document.getElementById('car').style.display="none"; 
            }
    }
</script>
```

I have also tried the following code below, to no success.

```
<div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'transport_allowance'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'transport_allowance',array(''=>'Select','600'=>'Car','Others'=>'Others'),array('onchange'=>'return muFun(this.value)')); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'transport_allowance'); ?>
</div>

<div id="others" style="display:none">
            <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'transport_allowance'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'transport_allowance'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'transport_allowance'); ?>
            </div>    
</div>

<script>
function muFun(obj){
            if(obj=='Others'){
            document.getElementById('others').style.display="block";
            }else{
            document.getElementById('others').style.display="none";
            }
    }
</script>
```

This code will only save 'Others' input but not 'Car'.

Thank you.

Comment: Managed to create a workaround by adding another field and inserting separately.

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes in your code please try below code

```
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'transport_allowance'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'transport_allowance',array('Car'=>'Car','Others'=>'Others')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'transport_allowance'); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="others" style="display:none">
            <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'transport_allowance'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model,'transport_allowance'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'transport_allowance'); ?>
            </div>    
    </div>
    <div id="car" style="display:none">
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->hiddenField($model,'transport_allowance',array('value'=>'450')); ?>
        </div>    
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Vehicle_transport_allowance").change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == 'Car') {
                    $('#car').show();
                    $('#others').hide();                    
                } else {
                    $('#others').show();
                    $('#car').hide();
                }
        });
    });
</script>
```